# Redirect logged in users to a specific PHP page

Tags: php, redirect

I have FreeHelpDesk.org on my website and I want to redirect logged in users to `fhd_dashboard.php` or `fhd_login.php`. By default, it will redirect to `index.php` which I dont want, because I made a lot of changes to `index.php` which is a login page. Is there anyway to deny accessing `index.php` by logged in users?

Comment: if($logged_in === TRUE){ die(); } - Would this not work for you? (Added to the index.php)

Comment: where i should put that? sry new to php

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: You would have to match it with your logged in variables and such, and at your index.php or where ever you want to deny your users access

Comment: for example , ticket.myweb.com . when a user which logged in before go to this page ( ticket.myweb.com) , it will redirect to index.php , i dont want to redirect to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.php page, once the sessions etc. are called and you have a way to tell if the user is logged in, you can add the following:

```html
// Assuming that here, if the user is logged in, then the 
// $logged_in variable is set to true/1 - edit this accordingly
// If the user is logged in
if($logged_in){
    
    //Redirect the user to the page that you want
    header("Location: fhd_dashboard.php");
}
```

This will redirect the user to fhd_dashboard.php instead of index.php.

Comment: where should i put this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 if($status=="loggedin") {
 header('Location: fhd_dashbord.php');
    exit;
} else {
    header('Location: fhd_login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: where to put this? in index.php? this is the first lines of my index.php : <?php include("includes/session.php");
if($status=="loggedin") {
 header('Location: fhd_dashbord.php');
    exit;
} else {
    header('Location: fhd_login.php');
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

You  Need Add This Code In Your Index.php file

```
$UserIsLogin;
if(//check user is login){
$UserIsLogin=true;
}else{
$UserIsLogin=false;
}
if($UserIsLogin==true) {
 header('Location: fhd_dashbord.php');
} else {
    header('Location: fhd_login.php');
}
```

Q1.You Store Information in $_Session?

Comment: what u mean about $session? i have a session.php file

Comment: I Say You Assign Login Information In $_SESSION  For Example Mysql_Qurey('Check username and Password '); if login successful Then Store The Information in session variable $_SESSION['login_Status']=true;                                                                    Finally Check if($_SESSION['login_Status']=true){  header('Location: fhd_dashbord.php');}   I Hope You Understand ? Or Send Your Full Code Of Sign And Index Page